# Nothing is happening when I call CollectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to call my method that highlights the UICollectionViewCells I have.. everything works normally but when the UIView first loads I am trying to select the first item in the collection view like this

```
[photoCollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
```

This is what my selection method looks like, that works well when selecting photos.

```
#pragma mark -- UICollectionView Delegate
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    oldCell = currentCell;
    currentCell = indexPath;

    // animate the cell user tapped on
    UICollectionViewCell  *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UICollectionViewCell *oCell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:oldCell];

    NSDictionary *currentSelectedDict = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *updatePreviewImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentSelectedDict objectForKey:@"DImage"]];
    [previewImageView setImage:updatePreviewImage];
    previewImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    typeTextF.text = [currentSelectedDict objectForKey:@"DocumentType"];
    descriptionText.text = [currentSelectedDict objectForKey:@"DocumentDescription"];
    dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [currentSelectedDict objectForKey:@"DateString"]];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^{
                         NSLog(@"animation start");
                         [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                         [oCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"animation end");
                         [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                         [oCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                     }
     ];


}
```

I have read that maybe you can call this method too early? I am not sure if that's the case but I don't know how to test it, or if the code I am using is even correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead. Override UICollectionViewCell class & add this method

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    [super setSelected:selected];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{

            self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }];     
}
```

Comment: nope thats not it.. I tried debugging with a break point and the method is never called.. so even if it did make it this far it wouldnt matter

Comment: ok sorry. I didnt see first line of code. when you programatically call didSelectItemAtIndexPath  it wont trigger the delegate method. it's called only when user tap on it. if you want to perform this animation when cell is selected. you have to override the uitableviewcell. ill try posting some code for my original answer.

Comment: okay so I have a subclassed collectionviewcell i will add this, then would i just call [cell setSelected:YES]; in the collectionview class

Comment: no :D .. you just do the selectItemAtIndexpath method as before... but in this case this will call setSelected Method in your collectionviewcell class automatically. you can comment the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method as it does nothing.

Comment: This is very good advice, but not directly related to the issue in the question. Have an upvote anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably calling the selection too early. You don't say where you are calling it from (except for "when the UIView first loads") but if you're calling it any earlier than viewDidAppear, the collection view will not have loaded any cells, and so you'll be selecting nothing.

You can confirm this with breakpoints - put one on the code where you select the cell, and one in your cellForItem method. If the selection one is hit first, you know the cells haven't been loaded.